# Which symbols can I use as shorthands to convey specific meanings?

Tags: punctuation, symbols

For example, "/" (slash) can be used to mean "or" for two things that are interchangeable:

> I am taking my car/automobile to meet with my date/girlfriend.

Are there other symbols like this that I can use as shorthand? (Except the mathematical ones,  *<, >, +, -, =, ≠*.)

I'm looking for one that would mean two terms are opposed to each other, are antagonists. For example "stand duck". What could I put in-between? I was wondering if "\" had any meaning.

Comment: I don't know, but I feel this question is off-topic.

Comment: I'd just reverse the words to end up with a [Duck Stand](http://www.flickriver.com/photos/tom_martin/5234209763/).

Answer (score 5):

Besides the virgule ("slash"), there aren't many glyphs that represent relationships outside of mathematical notation (including the Propositional Calculus), and none of them would be considered proper for use in formal writing. The ones you might see are → (becomes), ↔ (a reversible transition or an identity), ℅ (in care of), &, and @. There are a couple of others, like an overscored c, that are rarely included in anything other than professional font sets, that represent old manuscript abbreviations (the overscored c is "cum", or "with").

Even the virgule is only acceptable in certain kinds of formal writing, where the full expression in words would be tedious or awkward due to constant repetition. As jackgill mentions in his post, the meaning is ambiguous and contextual -- it can have the meaning of OR (and/or), XOR (one or the other, both not both) or opposition.

The backslash ("hack") is barely older than I am -- it's a child of computing.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that the backslash is actually this young. I'd have expected it to have some older, possibly obscure use before the re-invention in programming.

Comment: I might use → and ↔ someday.  Is there a list of those somewhere ? While I was posting my question I stumbled upon [wiki/Punctuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punctuation) some of them I've never seen before !

Comment: Ampersand (&) has more or less the same rules for usage as the virgule, just meaning "and" instead of "or".  That's always struck me as a bit odd, since it derived from "etc" rather than just "and"!

Comment: Actually, the ampersand is just a digraph of e and t -- one can often see *et cetera* abbreviated as *&c* and *et alia* as *&a* in older works.

Comment: @Stan: And current legal works, actually.

Comment: @Jon: I only read the *illegal* ones, myself.

Comment: @Jon Purdy: Where are lawyers using ampersands or latin contractions in English?

Comment: @Marcin: As far as I know, legal briefs make rather heavy use of Latin abbreviations, not usually & by itself, but certainly &c.

Comment: @Jon Purdy: And how far do you know?

Comment: @Marcin: Not particularly. It's accumulated hearsay combined with scraps of actual experience, like most things in language. I haven't been alive very long, after all.

Answer (score 2):

One symbol that hasn't been mentioned yet is the tilde, *~*. This symbol is very commonly used in technical writing, and means *about*, or *approximately*.  For example:

> The vessel is preheated to ~800 degrees Celcius.

Answer (score 1):

Forward slash, or /, can also be used to signify opposing things. For example, from the Wikipedia article on *male*:

> **Male/female** dimorphism between organisms or reproductive organs of different sexes is not limited to animals; male gametes are produced by chytrids, diatoms and land plants, among others.

Backslash has no specific meaning that I've ever seen.

Comment: Yes that's what I thought but I also thought it would be confusing if I used both meanings in the same sentence. I'm writing a manual and this is what I came up with "Focus/Ignore / Cancel Focus/Ignore" It's a chapter title and in it I'll be discussing all 3 terms.